# Graphics problem in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, graphics

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 (alongside Windows XP, dual boot), but there are two issues which are both missing graphics.

1) The first is that whenever I start up Ubuntu, I never see the loading screen that appears before the desktop is shown. The graphics is simply missing

2) The second is that whenever I open the "dash home", I can't see the icons of the various applications

I haven't done anything now besides installing Ubuntu. Is this a driver problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your computer for of all. Are you running 32 bit or 64 bit? What's the graphic card you are using? Are you running on Open Source Driver or proprietary( get on computer settings then software source, you can find what type of driver you are using) Maybe you are not running any drivers at all that might be the reason.

Also, are you in command lines? or you are on the desktop?

Comment: My computer is a Dell Lattitude D630, 32bit. The graphics card is a Nvidia Corporation G86M Quadro NVS 135M. I am using an open source driver ("using X.Org X server), but other NVIDIA alternatives are listed. I am on desktop.

Comment: I chose to use the NVIDIA driver (propretiary), and it seems to work. Thanks